# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2.2.0-rc.3

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack

**Trying to run npm install react-native but gives thisError**

+-- react-native-material-design@0.3.7

+-- shelljs@0.7.5

`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2.2.0-rc.3

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.1
npm WARN eslint-import-resolver-webpack@0.8.0 requires a peer of webpack@^1.11.0 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN html-webpack-plugin@2.24.1 requires a peer of webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native@0.44.0 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none was installed.

**My packet.json file with dependecies**

```
"dependencies": {
"babel-polyfill": "6.20.0",
"chalk": "1.1.3",
"compression": "1.6.2",
"cross-env": "3.1.3",
"express": "4.14.0",
"fontfaceobserver": "2.0.7",
"immutable": "3.8.1",
"intl": "1.2.5",
"invariant": "2.2.2",
"ip": "1.1.4",
"lodash": "4.17.2",
"minimist": "1.2.0",
"react": "15.4.1",
"react-dom": "15.4.1",
"react-helmet": "3.2.2",
"react-intl": "2.1.5",
"react-native": "^0.44.0",
"react-native-material-design": "^0.3.7",
"react-redux": "4.4.6",
"react-router": "3.0.0",
"react-router-redux": "4.0.6",
"react-router-scroll": "0.4.1",
"redux": "3.6.0",
"redux-immutable": "3.0.8",
"redux-saga": "0.14.0",
"reselect": "2.5.4",
"sanitize.css": "4.1.0",
"styled-components": "1.1.2",
"warning": "3.0.0",
"whatwg-fetch": "2.0.1"
 },
  "devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "6.18.0",
"babel-core": "6.21.0",
"babel-eslint": "7.1.1",
"babel-loader": "6.2.10",
"babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "1.0.0",
"babel-plugin-react-intl": "2.2.0",
"babel-plugin-react-transform": "2.0.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "6.18.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "6.9.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "6.8.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.2.11",
"babel-preset-latest": "6.16.0",
"babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
"babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "6.16.0",
"cheerio": "0.22.0",
"circular-dependency-plugin": "2.0.0",
"coveralls": "2.11.15",
"css-loader": "0.26.1",
"enzyme": "2.6.0",
"eslint": "3.11.1",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "13.0.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb-base": "10.0.1",
"eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.8.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.2.3",
"eslint-plugin-react": "6.7.1",
"eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "0.1.5",
"eventsource-polyfill": "0.9.6",
"exports-loader": "0.6.3",
"file-loader": "0.9.0",
"html-loader": "0.4.4",
"html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.1",
"image-webpack-loader": "2.0.0",
"imports-loader": "0.6.5",
"jest-cli": "18.0.0",
"lint-staged": "3.2.1",
"ngrok": "2.2.4",
"node-plop": "0.5.4",
"null-loader": "0.1.1",
"offline-plugin": "4.5.2",
"plop": "1.7.3",
"pre-commit": "1.1.3",
"react-addons-test-utils": "15.4.1",
"rimraf": "2.5.4",
"shelljs": "0.7.5",
"sinon": "2.0.0-pre",
"style-loader": "0.13.1",
"url-loader": "0.5.7",
"webpack": "2.2.0-rc.3",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "1.9.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.15.0"
  }
```

Comment: Did you work out anything for this? Any tips for those that follow in your footsteps?